# Supress the message of a new QGIS version in QGIS 3.4 by changing a Windows registry key

Tags: qgis, windows

In QGIS you can supress the message of announcing a new Version by changing the value of checkVersion parameter from true to false inside of QGIS.

In version 2.18 there is a corresponding Windows registry key and a administrator can change it without user action.

In version 3.4.1 i could not found a corresponding registry key.

How can i solve the Problem with QGIS 3.4.1  without user action?

Answer (score 5):

The values from the 2.x registry are now in

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\QGIS3.ini
```

Inside QGIS - set `allowVershionCheck` to `false` (the screenshot is outdated):
[image]